# django template tag running for loop not for all objects

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I want to run for loop for 4 objects but when i use .all method it runs for all objects, here is my code

```
{% for book in object.book_author.all %}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

because of .all method for loop runs for all books but I want only 4.

Comment: Filters not getting applied or you need to show only 4 out of whatever you get?

Comment: yes, out of all object i want to show only first 4 objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `slice` filter.

```
{% for book in object.book_author.all|slice:":4" %}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```